Proof of generalised laplace expansion
Let $A \in K^{n \times n}$. For any $I \in \mathcal{P}_k(n)$ of selected rows of $A$ we have $$\lvert A \rvert = \sum_{J \in \mathcal{P}_k(n)} (-1)^{I + J}\lvert A_{IJ}\rvert \lvert A_{I'J'} \rvert,$$
where $I + J = \sum_{i \in I} i + \sum_{j \in J} j$, $A_{IJ}$ is a minor of $A$ and $A_{I'J'}$ is its complement.
I do believe it should be easy to prove it using the definition of determinant, but that would be tedious and not elegant. The other way might be proving it by induction on dimension of $A$, as we can use the standard Laplace expansion and get a matrices from $K^{(n-1)\times (n-1)}$, but it still seems pretty tricky. Maybe another way could be induction on the cardinality of $I$ and using the fact that as $\lvert I \rvert$ gets larger, then $\lvert I' \rvert$ gets smaller. Is there any other way around it? Or could these options be done pretty directly without getting lost in details?

Have you looked at the proofs of it in other answers on this site?
